# Bootstrap web design having different measurements on different screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html code to be display on two different screens (device: iphone 6/7/8).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-4 bg-light">asdlo</div>
          <div class="col-4 bg-warning">asdlo</div>
       <div class="col-4 bg-light">asdlo</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

It appears that one of the output shows the column measurement to be 125.06 x 29.6 while another shows 125 x 24. May i know how to make sure the design is same in all the iphone devices? or this is just our screen setting that make the measurement different and result in slight different of design?

I am using Bootstrap 4 to design the mobile web.

Answer (score 1):

You can just inspect the code and click toggle device toolbar or ctrl+shift+m. Then you can see some responsive option at the top. Just click it and select your device and check whether its good or not.

If its not going good at particular width just note it down and use some media query in css

Answer (score 0):

Run your app in google chrome.  Use F12 to open the developer tools. In the left hand corner hit the button that looks like a phone

[image: phone mode]

From there you can emulate different devices.  You can pick iPhone.

See how it looks then write your css media query’s to set break points for your screen sizes

Have a look here to get your [css media queries by device](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)

Example:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 736px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

Comment: Hi i understand the screenshot you showed me, that is where i check my design. But now for example i have a normal div at Iphone 6/7/8, and the div appears to be longer at Iphone 6/7/8 PLUS. Does it means that i need to use media queries to set the div to be the size i want at iphone 6/7/8 PLUS?

Comment: also, i am using classes in bootstrap to set the paddings and margins such as class="pl-1 mt-1 mb-2" etc.

Comment: @JackyLim  yes you should wrap your pl-1 mt-1 mb-2 classes in the media queries and set the min width.  Then in the classes just adjust the width of the div accordingly

Comment: what do you mean wrap the classes in media queries?

Comment: I edited my answer above to include an example.   Where is says *styles go here *. Just put your css classes  there and adjust them accordingly inside that block.

Comment: okay thanks. I thought boostrap did everything for us so i never thought of using media queries until i get different design on another laptop screen. Much appreciated

Comment: Great!  Can you mark the answer as complete please ?

Comment: Hi, I try the query and it works well on my laptop (with chrome). But when i put on another laptop and open with chrome, the design is still different in a way that some component doesn't appear to be the size and position i set in the codes. May i know is it normal to get different design across different laptops?